# Error pushing image via docker registry v2 api

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I was start pushing an image to private docker registry after getting authorization token. However the request gets failed due to unauthorized access. There is not enough documentation on what are the body parameters that this particular endpoint expects.Could anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
curl -k -v -L -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -X POST "https://***/v2/helloworld/image1/blobs/uploads/"


> Host: ****
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlZDWUo6UDdWVjpTS1Q0OlVGNUM6VTVYMjpUR01YOk9QWUs6TTY2Rjo3UkZEOkJTSTI6VVJFSjpFUDMyIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJBdXRoIFNlcnZpY2UiLCJzdWIiOiIiLCJhdWQiOiJEb2NrZXIgcmVnaXN0cnkiLCJleHAiOjE0ODc2NTM2NDgsIm5iZiI6MTQ4NzY1MjczOCwiaWF0IjoxNDg3NjUyNzQ4LCJqdGkiOiI3ODI1ODcwNDY1NDc2Mjg4NzA3IiwiYWNjZXNzIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoicmVwb3NpdG9yeSIsIm5hbWUiOiJuZXV0cm9uL3JlYWN0aXZlLXByaWNpbmctb2ZmZXJzLWZ1bGZpbGxtZW50IiwiYWN0aW9ucyI6W119XX0.2zQ8GcbLlg26O-dgBQYXMEnOlsDfxonkjy5VhGmq325eDv69C5C28WHiFf6fTLBUNw6YnBv6Ty20ZakuzRPzUHq-C2IVyqMjSymYs_VaaKtRMSCLo-DtVgKL9sSDtWSRd6N2aOk8g5AeQvcs3FaYnE5QQCzho6t79zXd6vUYJV4
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 04:57:05 GMT
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Server: Apache
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://****/auth",service="Docker registry",scope="repository:****/****:pull,push",error="insufficient_scope"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 266
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Name":"***/***","Action":"pull"},{"Type":"repository","Name":"***/***","Action":"push"}]}]}
```

Note: I have admin access to the docker repository

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Is your registry-URL in the curl post command formed like this? `https://***:5000/..`

Comment: @lorenzvth7 Nope, i masked the host name with **** for confidential reason. It is well formed registry URL with proper hostname.

Comment: On which port is your registry exposed? 443 I suppose when you don't specify the port.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 Yes it is at port 443